# Finding Linear Independence in $P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra

We are asked to deteremine whether the vectors are linearly independent:

$ x^2 + 1, x + 1, x^2 + x $ in $P_3$

I began the problem as follows:

Let $ S $ = { $x^2 + 1, x + 1, x^2 + x$ } in $P_3$

$x+1 \rightarrow 0x^2 + x + 1 \rightarrow (0,1,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3$

$x^2+1 \rightarrow x^2 + 0x + 1 \rightarrow  (1,0,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3$

$x^2+x \rightarrow x^2 + x + 0 \rightarrow (1,1,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3$

Now, we augment this data into a matrix:

A = $ \begin{pmatrix}
       0 &  1 &  1 &|  0 \\
       1 &  0 &  1 &|  0 \\
       0 & 0 & 0 &| 0
    \end{pmatrix}
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
       c_1 \\
       c_2 \\
       c_3 
    \end{pmatrix}
$

Ref(A) = $ \begin{pmatrix}
       1 &  0 &  0 \\
       0 &  1 &  1 \\
       0 & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}
$

$\det(A) = 0$. Since the determinant is $0$, the set $S$ is linearly dependent.

Is this correct? Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

The method is correct. But you entered wrong entries.

$$x+1 \rightarrow (0,1,1)\\x^2+1\rightarrow (1,0,1)$$

And you don't need to augment the $c_i$ column. Just finding $\det{A}$ is enough. They should be linearly independent.